# Is my graph too big to practically work with?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a DiGraph in networkx with ~8M nodes ~30M edges. My goal is drop a subset (~1M) of these nodes and perform calculations on the remaining graph, adding attributes to nodes and edges based on relationships.

However it seems that even performing the first step of dropping nodes is impossible. What I have attempted:

**Goal: Drop all nodes that are not descendants of node 'a'.**

`nodesToKeep = nx.descendants(G, 'a')` Wall time: 40 s

`nodesToDrop = [n for n in G if n not in set(nodesToKeep )]` **Wall time: unclear, >24h**

I would then remove nodes using `G.remove_nodes_from(nodesToDrop)`

**The problem is that the runtime for even the list comprehension nodesToDrop is in itself so high.** I killed the process after ~24h.

**Is it generally not realistic to use networkx for graphs this size? Or is there some other approach I should be taking?**

Very grateful for any responses that might guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, using such a huge graph is often impractical. People who have such large graphs generally use sampling techniques to get the answers they are looking for. [Here](https://github.com/benedekrozemberczki/LittleBallOfFur) is a pretty extensive library that implements a very comprehensive list of sampling techniques. All of these techniques have their pros and cons, so it is worth reading up on them to understand exactly for what sort of problems they are intended for.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the reply. Will look at alternatives.